# Numpy - use values of array that meet condition

Tags: python, numpy

I have two numpy arrays, one of a boolean type, the other float type. I want to get the rows of XY_coord where one of the colums has a row with True (so all rows in XY_coord with False-False in BOOL are removed. How do I do this?

```
BOOL = np.array([[False,  True],
           [False,  True],
           [False,  True],
           [False,  True],
           [ True,  True],
           [ True, False],
           [False, False],
           [False, False],
           [ True, False]])
       
XY_coord =    np.array([[-192.9594843 ,   78.17485294],
           [-182.2699483 ,   50.143909  ],
           [-171.5804122 ,   22.11296505],
           [ -51.11635646,  132.2664039 ],
           [ -40.42682039,  104.2354599 ],
           [ -29.73728432,   76.20451597],
           [  90.72677139,  186.3579548 ],
           [ 101.4163075 ,  158.3270108 ],
           [ 112.1058435 ,  130.2960669 ]])
```

I can do:

```
XY_coord[out[:,0]]
XY_coord[out[:,1]]
```

and append the outcome, but my matrix is much larger, so this will be inefficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to solve this. Since you only care about dropping rows with `False, False` I would convert the `BOOL` array to a row index: `keep_row = BOOL.sum(axis=1).astype('bool')`. Then you can simply take `XY_coord[keep_row]` to get your filtered array.

Answer (score 1):

Try this-

```py
XY_coord[BOOL[:,0] | BOOL[:,1], :]
```